# Django ListView for same model in multiple URLs

Tags: django

I am trying to use a ListView on the same model for multiple URLs in Django. Specifically, I have a home page using `ListView` and `Pagination` for blog posts and I want to have an archive page using `ListView` without `pagination` with a different design. So I tried to do this:

**urls.py:**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
from blogengine.models import Post

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # index
    url(r'^(?P<page>\d+)?/?$', ListView.as_view(
        model=Post,
        paginate_by=4,
        )),
    # individual posts
    url(r'^(?P<slug>[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/?$', DetailView.as_view(model=Post,
                                                           )),
    # archive
    url(r'^archive/$', ListView.as_view(
        model=Post,
        )),
)
```

But what happens is Django just ignores the archive link because the class based view has already been used (so i just get a 404). What options do I have for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The url `/archive/` is matching the url pattern for the detail view. You have two options:

1. Move the archive url pattern above the detail url pattern. Note, this means you can't have a post with `slug="archive"`
2. Change the url pattern for individual posts so that it doesn't clash with the archive url pattern. For example:

   ```
   url(r'^posts/(?P<slug>[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/?$', DetailView.as_view(model=Post,
                                                      )),`
   ```